# Error: googleapi: Error 400: Field CONSENTS is type RECORD but has no schema, invalid

Tags: json, google-bigquery, terraform

I'm trying to create a BigQuery table using terraform.

Here is my schema :

```
{
  "dataset_id": "xxx_${location}_${project_env}",
  "table_id": "tb_xxx_user_info",
  "range_partitioning": null,
  "time_partitioning": null,
  "clustering": null,
  "description": "XXX Users",
  "deletion_protection": false,
  "labels" : {
       "env": "${project_env}",
       "location": "${location}",
       "data_layer": "specific-layer",
       "confidentiality": "c3",
       "description": "tb-lps-users"
  },
  "schema": [
      {
         "name": "CUSTOMER_ID",
         "type": "STRING",
         "mode": "REQUIRED",
         "description": "CUSTOMER_ID"
      },
      {
         "name": "SAP_NUMBER",
         "type": "STRING",
         "mode": "REQUIRED",
         "description": "SAP_NUMBER"
      },
      {
         "name": "COMPANY_NAME",
         "type": "STRING",
         "mode": "NULLABLE",
         "description": "COMPANY_NAME"
      },
      {
         "name": "EMAIL",
         "type": "STRING",
         "mode": "NULLABLE",
         "description": "EMAIL"
      },
      {
         "name": "PHONE_NUMBER",
         "type": "STRING",
         "mode": "NULLABLE",
         "description": "PHONE_NUMBER"
      },
      {
         "name": "CONTACTS",
         "type": "STRING",
         "mode": "NULLABLE",
         "description": "CONTACTS"
      },
      {
         "fields": [
            {
               "name": "OPTIN_MODIFICATION_DATE",
               "type": "DATETIME",
               "mode": "NULLABLE",
               "description": "OPTIN_MODIFICATION_DATE"
            },
            {
               "name": "CONSENT",
               "type": "STRING",
               "mode": "NULLABLE",
               "description": "CONSENT"
            }
         ],
         "name": "CONSENTS",
         "type": "RECORD",
         "mode": "REPEATED",
         "description": "CONSENTS"
      }
   ]
}
```

The schema is parsed with another file

Here the code of this file :

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "tables" {

  for_each = var.tables

  project     = var.project_id
  dataset_id  = each.value.dataset_id
  table_id    = each.value.table_id
  schema      = jsonencode(each.value.schema)
  clustering  = each.value.clustering
  description = each.value.description
  labels      = each.value.labels
  deletion_protection = each.value.deletion_protection

  dynamic "time_partitioning" {
    for_each = each.value.time_partitioning != null ? [each.value.time_partitioning] : []
    content {
      type                     = each.value.time_partitioning.type
      field                    = each.value.time_partitioning.field
      require_partition_filter = each.value.time_partitioning.require_partition_filter
    }
  }

  dynamic "range_partitioning" {
    for_each = each.value.range_partitioning != null ? [each.value.range_partitioning] : []
    content {
      field = each.value.range_partitioning.field
      range {
        start    = each.value.range_partitioning.start
        end      = each.value.range_partitioning.end
        interval = each.value.range_partitioning.interval
      }
    }
  }


  depends_on = [google_bigquery_dataset.datasets]
}
```

And here is the varaiable.tf :

```
variable "tables" {
  description = "A list of objects which include table_id, dataset_id, schema, clustering, time_partitioning, range_partitioning, expiration_time and labels."
  default     = {}
  type = map(object({
    dataset_id  = string
    table_id    = string,
    description = string,
    schema = list(object({
      name = string,
      type = string,
      mode = string,
      description = string
    })),
    clustering = list(string),
    deletion_protection = bool
    time_partitioning = object({
      expiration_ms            = number,
      field                    = string,
      type                     = string,
      require_partition_filter = bool
    }),
    range_partitioning = object({
      field    = string,
      start    = number,
      end      = number,
      interval = number
    }),
    labels     = map(string)
  }))
}
```

The error is : **Error: googleapi: Error 400: Field CONSENTS is type RECORD but has no schema, invalid**

I tried to add the value fields on variable.tf but as all the tables don't need necessarily a fields value then it crash again..

Could you please help me find the source of this error ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing this block of code.

```
     {
         "name": "CONSENTS",
         "type": "RECORD",
         "mode": "REPEATED",
         "description": "CONSENTS",
         "fields": [
            {
               "name": "OPTIN_MODIFICATION_DATE",
               "type": "DATETIME",
               "mode": "NULLABLE",
               "description": "OPTIN_MODIFICATION_DATE"
            }
         ]
      }
```

Or

You can add “{ }”  to the code.

```
    {
         "fields": [
            {
               "name": "OPTIN_MODIFICATION_DATE",
               "type": "DATETIME",
               "mode": "NULLABLE",
               "description": "OPTIN_MODIFICATION_DATE"
            },
            {
               "name": "CONSENT",
               "type": "STRING",
               "mode": "NULLABLE",
               "description": "CONSENT"
            }
         ],
        {
         "name": "CONSENTS",
         "type": "RECORD",
         "mode": "REPEATED",
         "description": "CONSENTS"
         }
     }
```

You can use this Bigquery [validator](https://bigquery-json-schema-generator.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer, but I found the solution :

Just need to put any into the type variable.

```
variable "tables" {
  description = "A list of objects which include table_id, dataset_id, schema, clustering, time_partitioning, range_partitioning, expiration_time and labels."
  default     = {}  
  type        = any
}
```